# How do i get count to work in this script

Tags: powershell

I need help understanding why $myCol_Table always have a count of 2

if i run  this part of the script

```
$vms = Get-VM 
ForEach ($vm in $vms) {$snapshots = Get-Snapshot -VM $vm | Where-Object { $_.Description -notlike "*RPData*"}
$myObj = $vm | Select-Object VM, NumSnapshots
$myObj.VM = $vm.name
$myObj.NumSnapshots = ($snapshots | measure-object).count
```

$myObj.NumSnapshots have a count of zero and the email is send and the body table is empty

anyone have a idea why ?

This is the full script

```
# Creation de l'usager et mot de passe 
$secpasswd = Get-content C:\password.txt | convertto-securestring
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("test\test", $secpasswd)

#Connection au vcenter 

Connect-VIServer -Server vcenter -Credential $mycreds 

# Trouver tout les VM

$vms = Get-VM  
$myCol = @()

# Trouver les Vm avec des snapshots 

ForEach ($vm in $vms) {$snapshots = Get-Snapshot -VM $vm | Where-Object { $_.Description -notlike "*RPData*"}
$myObj = $vm | Select-Object VM, NumSnapshots
$myObj.VM = $vm.name
$myObj.NumSnapshots = ($snapshots | measure-object).count



If ($myObj.NumSnapshots -ge '1'){

        $myCol += $myObj; }


# Utilisation de  PSObject pour créé une table HTML

$myCol_Table = $myCol | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

}


if ($myCol_Table.Count -ge 1)  {

$SMTPServer = "192.168.2.3"
$enc = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding
 Send-MailMessage -to "xxx@xxx" `
                 -from "xxx@xxx" `
                 -Subject "VM avec snapshot" `
                 -body $myCol_Body `
                 -smtpserver $SMTPServer `
                 -BodyAsHtml `
                 -Encoding $enc
                 }

Else {

Write "vide" }
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$myObj.NumSnapshots = ($snapshots | measure-object).count` with `$myObj.NumSnapshots = $snapshots.Length`? 
That's the .net-standard for measuring array-members.

Comment: i just tried and the email is still send and the Table is emply

Comment: You have a few variables there where I don't know where you have created them, for example `$myCol_Body`. Also, is there any reason why you're converting to HTML in parts instead of just doing it for any data in `$myCol` at the end?

Comment: @Ash the $myCol_Body is juste a the text i send in the email, it wrote in french so i left it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off my comment above. Here's an untested example, which just tidies things up a little more to eliminate mistakes with additional variables. Add your code to connect to the vCenter ahead of this, although I would suggest that you add your vCenter credentials to a session using `Get-Credential` yourself one time, and then export them under the context of a service account using [`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7), rather than use a password in a text file. You can re-import them with [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml?view=powershell-7).

```bsh
$col = @()
$vms = Get-VM
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $snapshots = ($vm | Get-Snapshot | Where-Object { $_.Description -notlike "*RPData*" } | Measure-Object).Count
    if ($snapshots -ge 1) {
        $col += [PSCustomObject] @{
            VM = $vm.Name
            NumSnapshots = $snapshots
        }
    }
}

if (($col | Measure-Object).Count -ge 1) {
    $body = $col | ConvertTo-Html

    $MailMessage = @{
        To = "xxx@xxx"
        From = "xxx@xxx"
        Subject = "VM avec snapshot"
        Body = $body
        SmtpServer = "192.168.2.3"
        BodyAsHtml = $true
        Encoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]
    }
    Send-MailMessage @MailMessage
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help